# How to return a public key from a WCF server to a client

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a WCF service where the service encrypts an incoming string from client application. How do i return the public key of server to the client so that it can decrypt the encrypted string returned from the WCF service?
Is there any other way of achieving?

Comment: Your thinking is wrong (at least in terms of secure implementations). What you require is a PKI system with a certificate certified by a 3rd party authority. Otherwise your strings are not truly secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JSON Web Token (JWT)**.

JWTs generally have three parts: a header, a payload, and a signature.

```
header = '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}'
```

HS256 indicates that this token is signed using HMAC-SHA256

The payload contains the claims that we wish to make:

```
payload = '{"loggedInAs":"admin","iat":1422779638}'
```

The signature is calculated by base64url encoding the header and payload and concatenating them with a period as a separator:

```
key           = 'secretkey'
unsignedToken = encodeBase64(header) + '.' + encodeBase64(payload)
signature     = HMAC-SHA256(key, unsignedToken)
```

Now token look like:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJsb2dnZWRJbkFzIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0MjI3Nzk2Mzh9.gzSraSYS8EXBxLN_oWnFSRgCzcmJmMjLiuyu5CSpyHI
```

In my WCF application i use JWT .dll for generate tokens like this.

```
public string GenToken()
    {
        byte[] key = new byte[];
       var payload= new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    { "idUsr", 1 },
                    { "nameUsr", admin},
                    {"accessTime",DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30)}

                 };
        string token = JWT.JsonWebToken.Encode(payload, key , JWT.JwtHashAlgorithm.HS256);
                   return token;
    }
```